# Unity приближение камеры к курсору

Tags: unity3d

Сделал приближение камеры к центру камеры, но как  сделать приближение камеры к курсору мыши ?
Код:

```
private void ZoomIn()
{
    if (Input.mouseScrollDelta.y > 0)
    {
         
        float newSize = cam.orthographicSize - zoomStep;
        cam.orthographicSize = Mathf.Clamp(newSize, minCamSize, maxCamSize);
    }
}

private void ZoomOut()
{
    if (Input.mouseScrollDelta.y < 0)
    {   
        
        float newSize = cam.orthographicSize + zoomStep;
        cam.orthographicSize = Mathf.Clamp(newSize, minCamSize, maxCamSize);
    }
}
```